# Django - credentials not working for CustomUser

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to make a custom user, but there's one problem, when i get request.user, it’s an instance of User, not an instance of CustomUser, so i don’t get the extra fields and methods. I've found [this](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance.1.html), but when i'm trying to login in the django admin it won't work anymore.

Here is my code:
models.py

```
class CustomUser(User):
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Europe/Bucharest')
    porecla = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    selectat = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UserManager()
```

auth_backends.py -  so i can use the methods of the custom user when using request.user

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.apps import apps


class CustomUserModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = self.user_class.objects.get(username=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except self.user_class.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return self.user_class.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except self.user_class.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    @property
    def user_class(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_user_class'):
            self._user_class = apps.get_model(*settings.CUSTOM_USER_MODEL.split('.', 2))
            if not self._user_class:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured('Could not get custom user model')
        return self._user_class
```

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('football_app.auth_backends.CustomUserModelBackend', )
CUSTOM_USER_MODEL = 'football_app.CustomUser'
```

admin.py

```
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'selectat', )

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you are referring to is outdated. If you want to create a custom User model, the way to go is to subclass AbstractUser in stead of User. This is explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) in the official docs.